# What is the relation of len() function with int data type?

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple Python program to find the data type using `type` function.

```
x=input("what is your name?")
print(type(x))
```

It gives the output:

```
<class 'str'>
```

But when I add the `len` function"

```
x=len(input("what is your name?"))
print(type(x))
```

It gives the output:

```
<class int>
```

why is that? Can someone explain to me? Does `len` function change it to `int` type? what I have been told is `len` function works with string types only if we wanna find out the number of character in string.

Comment: The `len` function returns the length of the string, which happens to be an integer.

Comment: Learn more about the `len` function here : https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp

Comment: Looking at the *value* of `x` rather than its *type* would probably clear things up. `input` still returns a string, so `len` *is* being used with a string type. (It's also false that `len` *only* works with `str`; it works with anything that has a `__len__` method, including lists, tuples, dicts, sets, etc.)

Comment: Who told you `len` only works with strings? And what return type did you expect to represent the length of something if _not_ `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The len function returns the length of the string, which happens to be an integer.

> When the object is a string, the len() function returns the number of
> characters in the string.

Learn more about the len function here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp

---

To clear up things :-

```
input_string = input("what is your name?")
input_string_length = len(input_string)

print(type(input_string)) # <class 'str'>
print(type(input_string_length)) # <class int>
```

Thus, as you can see, the input string is not affected in any way and is not converted to the int type.

Answer (score 0):

```
len(input("what is your name?"))
```

returns the length of the input string as you can see in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=len#len). The length is stored as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression *inside* of the `len` function is a `str` (it could be other data types as well - for example, a `list`), but that does not mean that the whole expression is still a `str`.

Let's break down what happens when Python sees the line of code:

`print(type(len(input("what is your name?"))))`

1. Python starts by getting the innermost string, which is the [literal](https://thabo-ambrose.medium.com/what-is-a-literal-in-computer-programming-560eace90b5b) `str` `"what is your name?"`.
2. Python then calls the `input` builtin function on this `str`, and this **[returns](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/)** another `str`, inputted by the user.
3. Next, the builtin function `len` is called on the string **returned** by the `input` function. The value inputted into `len` is still of type `str`, but the new value returned by `len` is now an `int`. The original string is discarded and we are left with an `int` instead.
4. After this, the builtin function `type` is called on the new `int` value and returns that it is an integer. Note, it is giving the type of the `int` value returned by the `len` function, **not** the `str` value returned by the `input` function.
5. Finally, the builtin function `print` is called on the new `type` value, and prints the output `<class 'int'>`. The `print` function returns `None`

This can perhaps be seen more clearly using a diagram:

```py
----EXPRESSION----                     ----OUTPUT----

str: "what is your name?"
          |
          |  function: input  ------->  what is your name?
          v
str: value inputted by user
     e.g. "goose"
          |
          |  function: len
          v
int: length of value inputted
     e.g. 5
          |
          |  function: type
          v
type: <class 'int'>
          |
          |  function: print  ------->  <class 'int'>
          v
NoneType: None
```

Answer (score 0):

considering your example

```
x=input("what is your name?")
```

The inputs are stored in the variable x. Remember that when using **input()**, irrespective of the data type of the user input, the user’s value input is stored in some variable **(x in your case)** in the form of a string

``[string as input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtzsY.png) [character as input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BaDO.png) [integer as input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jT4a.png)

now coming towards the second part of your question regarding

```
x=len(input("what is your name?"))
```

it should be clear that **len** function always gives the length or the number of characters of the parameter passed as the input to it, so it is clear that the number of characters will always have a data type of integers.

**Example :** suppose **x = stack overflow**, which is the user's input. since the string **stack overflow** has **14** characters including the space,  it's length will be 14, and 14 is an integer. so the data type of the **len** function applied to it will be integer.

[len on a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtmsU.png)

same is the case if a single character is given as an input

[char on a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRiBa.png)

Comment: Answer is disorganized and verbose (particularly because of extraneous examples) and contains misleading language (particularly that "results" are "stored" in variables) rivaling the highly confused question.

Comment: @LorenzoGatti made some changes and simplified it as much as i could. Hopefully the answer is clear this time !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).